# zxing QR decoding returning null

Tags: qr-code, zxing, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use the unity version of zxing to decode a QR code.

Here is the code:

texture = gameObject.GetComponent();

```
    //texture.pixelInset = new Rect(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 4, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2);
    int imageSize = 100;

    Texture2D text2D = new Texture2D(imageSize, imageSize);

    text2D = (Texture2D)texture.texture;

    Debug.Log("text2D.GetPixels32().Length " + text2D.GetPixels32().Length);
    //Debug.Log("text2D.GetRawTextureData().Length " + text2D.GetRawTextureData().Length);

    Color32LuminanceSource source = new Color32LuminanceSource(text2D.GetPixels32(), imageSize, imageSize);        
    RGBLuminanceSource source1 = new RGBLuminanceSource(text2D.GetRawTextureData(), imageSize, imageSize);

    Debug.Log(GetString(source.Matrix));

    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

    BinaryBitmap bitmap1 = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source1));

    QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();

    BarcodeReader reader1 = new BarcodeReader();

    DecodingOptions options = new DecodingOptions();

    options.TryHarder = true;

    Result resultQRCodeReader = reader.decode(bitmap, options.Hints);
    Result resultQRCodeReader1 = reader.decode(bitmap1, options.Hints);

    Result resultBarcodeReader = reader1.Decode(source);
    Result resultBarcodeReader1 = reader1.Decode(source1);
```

The problem is the all 'Result' from both readers and both sources return a null string. 
I have tried several examples of a qrcode, which i tested in the zxing barcode tool- https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx, and they are all fine.

Can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: To which object is that script attached to? Try printing out few lines from text2D.GetPixels32() array to see if it has good values.. You can also use text2D.GetPixels32() directly in the reader.decode(color32array,width,height)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was setting the texture size to an arbitrary size of 100. 
The size passed to the Luminance source should be that of the original texture. So the right code should be:

```
 //texture.pixelInset = new Rect(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 4, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2);

Texture2D text2D = new Texture2D(imageSize, imageSize);

int imageSize = text.height;

text2D = (Texture2D)texture.texture;

Debug.Log("text2D.GetPixels32().Length " + text2D.GetPixels32().Length);
//Debug.Log("text2D.GetRawTextureData().Length " + text2D.GetRawTextureData().Length);

Color32LuminanceSource source = new Color32LuminanceSource(text2D.GetPixels32(), imageSize, imageSize);        
RGBLuminanceSource source1 = new RGBLuminanceSource(text2D.GetRawTextureData(), imageSize, imageSize);

Debug.Log(GetString(source.Matrix));

BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

BinaryBitmap bitmap1 = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source1));

QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();

BarcodeReader reader1 = new BarcodeReader();

DecodingOptions options = new DecodingOptions();

options.TryHarder = true;

Result resultQRCodeReader = reader.decode(bitmap, options.Hints);
Result resultQRCodeReader1 = reader.decode(bitmap1, options.Hints);

Result resultBarcodeReader = reader1.Decode(source);
Result resultBarcodeReader1 = reader1.Decode(source1);
```

*assuming this is a power of 2 texture